# Probability of finding the Quantum entity and atomic randomness

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am an undergraduate mathematics student and start learning Quantum Mechanics by my own interest. I am read the following books:

- **The Theoretical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics by Belal E. Baaquie**
- **A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics John S. Townsend**

After reading some of the chapters I got some question which I couldn't resolve my own. It will be a great help if someone help me to figure out those.

---

**Q1:** How does the probability of finding the energy (or position or momentum) of an electron change with time?

**Q2:** Why does the microscopic/atomic randomness occur naturally with respect to time?

---

I would appreciate if someone explained those with some intuition as I haven't a strong physics background and also any reference/resource will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Since this a Q&A site, please avoid having several questions in the same post. Edit this one to keep only one question, and creatre new posts for the others.

Comment: Thanks, @Miyase. I removed some questions. Let me know If I need to do something else.

Comment: For your first question, you'll want to read about the evolution operator. For your second question, can you clarify what your definition is for "microscopic randomness"? Quantum theory has an intrinsic aspect randomness, so you have to be more precise about what you want to know.

Comment: So far, I had learned the randomness in momentum and energy.  But it seems there are other entity which might be the same nature. For me, I would be interested in momentum and energy @Miyase

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer about "randomness", since this seems to be the core of your question.

A wavefunction evolves deterministically, without any randomness, following Schrödinger's equation. The fact that it is in a superposition state doesn't change anything at this point.

The random element appears when the wavefunction "collapses". What that means remains a bit of an open debate, but sticking to what most physicists know and use, the collapse happens during a measurement, or naturally during interaction with the environment (which really is a sort of measurement). When it does, the final state of the system will be randomly select from the states contained in the superposition.

Edit: consider a system whose wavefunction is a superposition of position states. I'll use discrete notations for simplicity, but it could be an integrale:

$$\lvert\psi\rangle=\sum_i\alpha_i\lvert x_i\rangle$$

If you measure the position of this system, or if the environment selects position eigenstates, the probability to get $x_i$ as a result is:

$$P_i=\lvert\langle x_i|\psi\rangle\rvert^2=\lvert \alpha_i\rvert^2$$

It's a direct consequence of one of the first laws you learn in quantum physics, [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule).

Comment: "When it does, the final state of the system will be **randomly select** from the states contained in the superposition." Can you give/redirect me any paper which explain it mathematically step by step? @Miyase

Comment: Any basic book will explain it, it's the most famous result. I'll edit my answer above in a minute.